# Linux - recommended apps to open a file

Tags: linux

In Ubuntu Linux, let's say I create a simple text file. When I right click that file, there is option to `open with other application`. It will show a list of `recommeded applications` which could open a text file.

My question is that how does the OS know which app can open that file ? What does the app developer have to do to make it a candidate ?

**Edit** : What I also want to ask is that does the OS verify this in any way (that the developer has specified the app to open a particular file format) ; for e.g. a video playing application could mention itself to open a text file, but when the user tries to use it, there will be a problem.

Comment: I don't know the answer but if you haven't been already you could take a look at freedesktop.org as they publish several standards that are to greater or lesser degree followed by major distros and DEs e.g. this page might be interesting http://standards.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/menu-spec-1.0.html

Comment: Can you point out what exactly does the developer need to do in the application ?

Comment: Try `man update-desktop-database`. The developer needs to provide a desktop file (launcher) with the right MimeType set, and have it installed in the right place (normally under /usr/share/applications). The rest will be done by the DE. The DE will blindly trust the developer. If you say your application can open text files, then your application will be listed in the menu for text files.

Comment: @n.m. The desktop file has a `mime type` .. is that what is used to determine which app can open a text file ? Mime type in `gedit` is `text/plain`

Answer (score 0):

Try creating Your app's `.desktop` file for showing your app in the `Open with other application` dialog. the `.desktop` file should look something like this

```
    [Desktop Entry]
    Encoding=UTF-8
    Name=<appName>
    Comment= some detail about the app
    Exec=<appName> %u
    Terminal=true
    Type=Application
    Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/<appName>.svg
    Categories=Application;Utility;TextEditor;
    StartupNotify=true
    MimeType=text/plain;
    NoDisplay=true
```

Save this as `~/.local/share/applications/<appName>.desktop` and the application will be automatically shown on `Open with other application` to be selected as default application.

The options for the `.desktop` files are many but its important to know what they mean.

[nautilus-actions.org](http://www.nautilus-actions.org/?q=node/377) supplies a very good guide and explanations for creating your `.desktop` files and all the possible parameters that you can use on them so if you have any doubts about creating a special `.desktop` file you can visit the site and look at the examples there.

**Note:-** not sure if OS verifies if its a video playing application or not, but even if it would it will verify with `MimeType` and if the app have `txt/plain` and it a video player it would fail, but again i'm not sure on this.